# Thumbnail and image sizes

Tags: html, css

I have three images of which sit inside of a thumbnail box. When viewing the site full screen or at any dimension under 2000 width (screen size) the images appear fine and inline - however, between 2000 and 4000 dimensions (just before full screen) the images seem to break their "inline" code because of the size of the images and the thumbnail box they're sitting in causing one of the images to appear below the two so that it may still fit within the thumbnail. Is there anyway to tell the three images within the thumb nail to shrink to a certain size so that they may stay inline due to the specific width of the screen?

Here's my current HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-4 ">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div align="center">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/HSC_Logo150.jpg"
                 alt="HSC Application"
                 style="display: inline" />
            <img src="~/Content/Images/NMMB_logo_v2.png"
                 style="display: inline; height: 150px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; " />
            <img src="~/Content/Images/LACredFinal.jpg"
                 style="display: inline;" />
        </div>
```

Comment: You mean [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)? (together with `height: auto`)

Comment: In the future, please edit your original question with additional information rather than posting in comments.